# PHP does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a code that looks like this:

```
jQuery.post("test1send.php", { browName : browser, timeCan: testTimeCanvas , timeSVG: testTimeSVG });

window.location.href = 'http://localhost/start/prosteTest2.html';
```

.php file looks like:

```
<?php
 $browName = $_POST['browName'];
 $timeCan = $_POST['timeCan'];
 $timeSVG = $_POST['timeSVG'];

    if($browName=='Opera'){
    $rowsCount = count(file('Data\Test1\Test1Opera.csv'));
    $fp = fopen('Data\Test1\Test1Opera.csv', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $rowsCount);
    fwrite($fp, ',');
    fwrite($fp, $timeCan);
    fwrite($fp, ',');
    fwrite($fp, $timeSVG);
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
    }else if($browName=='Firefox'){
    $rowsCount = count(file('Data\Test1\Test1Firefox.csv'));
    $fp = fopen('Data\Test1\Test1Firefox.csv', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $rowsCount);
    fwrite($fp, ',');
    fwrite($fp, $timeCan);
    fwrite($fp, ',');
    fwrite($fp, $timeSVG);
    fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
    }
 ?>
```

It should send variables to php and load next page. PHP should save variables to .csv file but it does not work. If there is no "window.location.href"  it works fine but when there is command to go to next page PHP does nothing. Does it need some delay to do PHP first and then go to next page??

Comment: Might want to consider changing your title. Though it did get my attention.

Comment: I know that title is wrong but i dont know how else i should name it

Comment: Call the window.location.href on success of your AJAX request. I think that what you might be experiencing is a redirect prior to the send because of the way your code is laid out. Something like:
`$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://we.com/",
data: {somedata: datahere },
success: function() {
window.location.href = "where you want them to go";
}
});`

Comment: put your `window.location.href` in a call back function

Comment: Don't change the title.  It's perfect!  :)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I saw the title and I was totally disappointed to find ZERO ranting: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the window.location.href in the success callback of the post - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
jQuery.post("test1send.php", { browName : browser, timeCan: testTimeCanvas , timeSVG: testTimeSVG }, function(){ window.location.href = 'http://localhost/start/prosteTest2.html'; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it needs a delay.  When you do `window.location.href = ...`, you tell the browser to cancel the current request before it's had time to process.

The easiest thing would probably be

```
jQuery.post("test1send.php", { ...}).done(function() {
    window.location.href = ...
});
```

although there are a number of equivalent techniques.  And if the post can fail, you might want to handle that with `.fail()` as well.

Comment: In recent versions of jQuery, there's also an `.always()` callback that fires on completion, whether it be success or failure. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/